# Works fine on local host but api calls give error when deployed version is executed (Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms)

Tags: mern, render.com

I am building a MERN app where people can share their recipes.
I am facing this error on any API calls
Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms.
Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

I don't get it this error only occurs when I run the deployed version of my MERN app. on my local system every thing works fine.
I Have deployed it on render.com

I Tired redeploying but nothing change.
check my DB connection, uri sting and every thing but no problem there since the application is running on local host the only problem occurs when I run the deployed app.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant code (and only the relevant code) in your question. If you don't know which code is relevant, do some debugging. See [mcve] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The issue I encountered while deploying MongoDB on Render.com was related to environment variables. Render.com offers two methods to include these variables:

1. Secret file: This method involves bundling all variables into a single file.
2. Separate inclusion: Each variable is included separately.

Initially, I used the first method (the secret file), but it didn't work for me. Upon switching to the second method (including variables separately), the problem was resolved successfully. If you're facing similar issues, consider using the second method for configuring your environment variables on Render.com.